# How to InfoWindowAdapter and onMArkerClick in Fragment

Tags: android, dictionary, fragment

in Activity class i ihave this code:

```
    class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

    private  View view;

    public MyInfoWindowAdapter(){

        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_globo_marker,null);

    }

    //implemets metod of MyInfoWidowAdapter
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title));
            tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
            return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //ActionBar Contextual
    mActionMode = InstalacionesEncontradasMostradasEnMapaActivity.this.startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack(marker));
    mActionMode.setTitle(marker.getTitle());


    return false;
}
```

Now i am working in Fragment. and i have two errors.

one in this line (The method is undefined):

```
view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_globo_marker,null);
```

and in this line (the method start action mode is undefined):

```
mActionMode = InstalacionesEncontradasMostradasEnMapaFragment.this.startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack(marker));
```

Comment: Sorry. the problem is I can not compile. "the method getlayoutinflater() is undefined for the type InfoInstalacionesEncontradasFragment.MyInfoWindowsAdapter" and "the method startActionMde (InstalacionesEncontradasFragment.ActionBarCallback) is undefine for the type InfoInstalacionesEncontradasFragment"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: `Activity != Fragment`.

In order to get a `LayoutInflater` instance, you'll need a `Context`. Various options (from inside a fragment):

```
getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(...);
LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(...);
((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(...);
```

Similar problem for `startActionMode()`. This method is only available to an `Activity`, hence you'll need to call it on one:

```
getActivity().startActionMode(...)
```

Or if you're using the Support Library:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(...)
```

(Although it would probably be better to [make the activity and fragment communicate](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) with each other in a more flexible way.)